# Attribute from nested class, python

Tags: python, class

i need help with printing attributes from nested class.

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    class NestedClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.attribute = 1
    ...
    print(self.SimpleClass.attribute) # this doesnt work, how can i print attribute ?
```

I really dont know how to call it, i tried everything i knew, e.g.:

```
print(SimpleClass.NestedClass.attribute)
print(NestedClass.attribute)
```

... but nothing works

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`attribute` is only created for an instance of `NestedClass` after the constructor is called. There is no initial value of `attribute`. If you did want to have a default value then you could do something like..

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    class NestedClass(object):
        attribute = 0
        def __init__(self):
            self.attribute = 1
```

The base class starting value of `attribute` is 0, and any instances will be 1

```
>>> SimpleClass.NestedClass.attribute
0
>>> SimpleClass.NestedClass().attribute
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing braces:

```
print(SimpleClass().NestedClass().attribute)
```

or

```
print(SimpleClass.NestedClass().attribute)
```